# WCF sync call with Task Parallel library

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

In my new project I started developing the WPF client. For a better unit testing experience I chose to use sync service calls.
Now I face the situation that the amount of data I call the service for is not that small, so it will take some time until the call returns.
I'm not sure wether to wrap my sync service calls into TPL Tasks or should I generate asynchronous service proxies?

Comment: If you can use C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5, you should generate async proxies and use `async/await` wherever possible. It is certainly easier, less error-prone and often more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I am limited to .Net 4.0.